# Confused on reflection coeffcient of Fresnel equations

Tags: pbr, material, fresnel

I am reading a paper about layered materials. However, I am confused on the implementation of this paper. The following picture describe the layered material. [image]

r_ab is a complex reflection coeffcient when going from medium a to medium b.

And in the code, there is:

```
        float2 R12, phi12;
        fresnelDielectric(LdotH, 1.0, eta_2, R12, phi12);
        float2 R21 = R12;
```

I don't understand why is r_12 equal to r_21?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $t_{12} = t_{21}$, by [the law of reciprocity](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/5286/the-reciprocity-of-brdf). Also, $$r_{12} + t_{12} = 1\\r_{21} + t_{21} = 1$$
It follows that $r_{12} = r_{21}$ as well.

Comment: Ahh..I don't understand why t_12 = t_21...

Comment: @TIANLUNZHU It's because of the law of reciprocity, a fundamental principle of optics. It says if you swap the incoming and outgoing rays, the BSDF (reflectance or transmittance) doesn't change. Note from the diagram that the $t_{12}$ and $t_{21}$ cases are exactly symmetrical with each other, only with the rays going in the opposite directions.